# Uploading folders php

Tags: php, copy, directory

Lets say I have a folder full of about fifty pictures I'd just taken on a photo shoot and I wanted to upload all of them to my website. So instead of having to select every single one and upload it, I could just upload the folder that they're in. Yet being that the browsers won't let you select folders, I know I could make it so you copy and paste the path to that folder, yet that would be ugly,hackish and complicated. Is there a better way to get around uploading a folder instead of having to do that? And if I do have to do that, will copy() work on folders or will I have to use a recursive loop to get all the pictures out of that folder and any folders within it?

Comment: You could use FTP to upload the pictures.

Comment: I believe Adobe AIR has some some filesystem hooks that would allow you to make a custom uploader. You'd want the fallback to be generic `input:file` fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP itself is unable to handle such a task because it must rely on the HTML interface to communicate with the client. If you are using HTML5, or if your clients use browsers with the appropriate support, you can use the multiple attribute for the file `input` element to handle this task.

For versions of HTML prior to HTML5, You will need to add a tool that can handle multiple file uploads, such as [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/)(Flash), [jUpload](http://jupload.sourceforge.net/)(Java applet), or [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) (jQuery).

Answer (score 3):

you should add the `multiple` attribute to the `input:file` element. That way you can select as many files as you want via a single `input:file` field.

Comment: Note: This attribute is only available in HTML5.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong: I thought this was one of those cases of the spec chasing the implementation. I'm pretty sure most browsers support `input:file[multiple]` even if they're not particularly HTML5 compliant.

Comment: I just tested in Chrome 12 and FF 5.0 using an XHTML 1.0 Strict doctype, and was indeed able to use a multi-upload control. So your thought appears to be correct: this may have more to do with browser implementation than HTML version.

Comment: @zzzzBov and @George Cummins, sadly I'm using it as a backend plugin for expressionengine and they use HTML 4. Is there maybe some other way around this or I think I heard of a JS script that could allow you to select it in HTML 4.

Comment: @SDuke: As I mentioned in my answer, Uploadify is one example (there are several) of Javascript implementations of multiple file uploads.

Comment: @SDuke, just because it isn't in the HTML4 spec doesn't mean you can't use it. Unless there is a definite reason to have *absolutely* valid HTML4, add the attribute and see if it works. If the browser doesn't support `[multiple]` then the user will just have to upload one file at a time. Using an AIR or JS override are typically preferred just because they (usually) improve the UX.

Comment: @zzzzBov I have already tested it and it didn't work, I believe my friend has a JS script that'll do it so I'll try to get it from him, if not I'll try to decode the Uploadify thing @George Cummins suggested.

Comment: @SDuke, then you ought to mark @George Cummins answer as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply: It isn't possible just with html form. Just zip them and unzip them on server side.

Answer (score 0):

Until HTML5 browsers take over the world, or you use client-side solutions based on Flash or Java, the ONLY way you'll be able to upload multiple files is by providing a `<input type="file" ...>` for each file you want uploaded.

Allowing file uploads from browsers is a major security risk, so the file inputs are one of the most heavily policed/regulated elements in browsers - allowing any kind of programmability opens the door to an exploit being able to suck any file(s) the attack wants from the client machine.

Comment: @Mark B this is being used as a plugin for the expressionengine backend.

Comment: Doesn't matter what's running on the server, you're still limited to what the browser will allow.

Answer (score 0):

I do this for my wifes website http://www.beccablake.com.  She is also a photographer.  I created a custom module (she uses drupal as the CMS) to upload a zip file containing all the pictures.  Once uploaded I extract the zip and iterate through all the files and create new nodes for each one.  Here is a snippet of code from that module that may help you do what you want.

```
<?php
$file = 'path/to/zip/pictures.zip';
$dest = 'path/to/pictures/directory';
exec('unzip "'. $file .'" -d '. $dest);
// If you need to do something with each file (like I do)
$files = scandir($dest);
?>
```

This assumes you can perform an 'exec' on your server to unzip.  My code is a lot different as I do more with the pics since its in Drupal, I create a proofing gallery and each picture is its own node so users can comment/rate/favorite the photos... etc.

Good Luck!

Comment: just be sure that you're sanitizing your input. Otherwise a malicious user could run anything they want via command line.

Answer (score 0):

The browser will never transmit any information about the client's directory structure, so such a general solution as you envision it is not possible in terms of directories. What you can hope for is that clients will offer a facility to turn a user's directory selection into a list of contained files, but in any event this would not be of any concern to you on the server side.